# How to properly aggregate timeseries data using Pandas into DataFrames instead of Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, time-series

This comes from the book 'Practical Time Series Analysis's chapter 2, since it's from the very beginning, I'm trying to follow along step by step. I wrote a notebook showing the error [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1haq15AeIohE3T0mLtviWNAXwQqFQFlj8#scrollTo=78hyhwXoieEn) the deal is as follows.

We are trying to sumarize information on a weekly basis and then joining the information from two sources: [Weekly user information about how many emails were open](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PracticalTimeSeriesAnalysis/BookRepo/master/Ch02/data/emails.csv) and [actual user donation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PracticalTimeSeriesAnalysis/BookRepo/master/Ch02/data/donations.csv), including amount donated and timestamp of donation.

We start the process by creading a complete idx for the email dataset, filling in 0s for the missing data:

```
complete_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((set(emails.week),
                                      set(emails.user)))
all_email = emails.set_index(['week', 'user']).reindex(complete_idx, fill_value = 0).reset_index()
all_email.columns = ['week', 'member', 'EmailsOpened']
```

Then the trailing zeroes of each series is removed.

```
cutoff_dates = emails.groupby('user').week.agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index()
cutoff_dates = cutoff_dates.reset_index()
for _, row in cutoff_dates.iterrows(): 
  member     = row['user']
  start_date = row['min']
  end_date   = row['max'] 
  all_email.drop(all_email[all_email.member == member]
                 [all_email.week < start_date].index, inplace=True) 
  all_email.drop(all_email[all_email.member == member]
                 [all_email.week > end_date].index, inplace=True)
```

So far so good. The problems start when we take a look at the donations. Initially we set a proper index using timestamp to later do a group by and apply a lambda function to resample the information into weeks, and summing the amount for each week

```
donations.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(donations.timestamp)
donations.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
agg_donations = donations.groupby('user').apply(lambda df: df.amount.resample("W-MON").sum().dropna())
```

The odd part is that our resampled result is a Series, and not a DataFrame, while this doesn't seem like an issue, the following example of the book tries to merge the data, afik, it's doing a SQL-JOIN using the user and time fields as keys:

```
for member, member_email in all_email.groupby('member'):
  member_donations = agg_donations[agg_donations.member == member]

  member_donations.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True) 
  member_email.set_index    ('week', inplace = True) 

  member_email = all_email[all_email.member == member]
  member_email.sort_values('week').set_index('week') 

  df = pd.merge(member_email, member_donations, how = 'left', 
                              left_index = True, 
                              right_index = True)
  df.fillna(0) 

  df['member'] = df.member_x 
  merged_df = merged_df.append(df.reset_index()[['member', 'week', 'emailsOpened', 'amount']])
```

The first issue is that you can't use brackets to filter data in series like you can using dataframes in this case `member_donations = agg_donations[agg_donations.member == member]` we can easily fix this by accessing each member direcly `agg_donations[member]` but then the next line, which tries to set the index, fails because Series object has no attribute 'set_index', which means that I should have a DataFrame before entering the for loop.

Why is `agg_donations = donations.groupby('user').apply(lambda df: df.amount.resample("W-MON").sum().dropna())` returning a series? How can turn that into a DataFrame with the proper columns?

The result should bring the amount of emails opened per week by user with the corresponding amount donated that week.

Answer (score 0):

Going in blind Pandas is always an adventure, but hey, I think I got where I should get.

First thing is to recreate the agg_donations Series as a proper DataFrame where DateTime will be the index, member and donation the columns. So I'll first pick the user column by unstacking the series on the appropriate axis:

```
userlist = list(agg_donations.unstack().axes[0])
```

With that in hand I can loop over all user, extract the information from the original dataframe, add in the member colum and append everything to a new dataframe:

```
df_agg_don = pd.DataFrame()
for u in userlist:
  dict1 = agg_donations[u]
  temp_df = pd.DataFrame(agg_donations[u])
  temp_df['member'] = u
  df_agg_don = df_agg_don.append(temp_df)
```

Now the merge loop will change a little to reflect the changes:

```
member_donations = df_agg_don[df_agg_don.member == member]
member_email = all_email[all_email.member == member]
```

We can still get the parts related to each member by using this, but the member_email needs some fixing related to its index so the join works properly.

```
member_email.set_index('week', inplace = True) 
member_email.index = pd.to_datetime(member_email.index)
```

After the merge we will also sort the data

```
  df = pd.merge(member_email, member_donations, how = 'left', 
                              left_index = True, 
                              right_index = True)
  df = df.sort_values('week').fillna(0)
```

Before adding everything to the merged_df

```
df['member'] = df.member_x 
merged_df = merged_df.append(df.reset_index()[['member', 'week', 'EmailsOpened', 'amount']])
```

The next code can be copied-executed from the book so it provides the correct values from the next example on the following page.

```
df = merged_df[merged_df.member == 998]
df['target'] = df.amount.shift(1)
df = df.fillna(0)
print(df.sort_values('week'))
```